# Using split_part in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column of data that has a number of different values:

```
123-AB
234-BC
456-CD
CA-421
KL-345
```

I want to remove any values before and after the "-" so the table should read as:

```
123
234
456
421
345
```

To remove anything after the "-", I tried using Select split_part (column name, '-', 1)   from table_name and it worked.

Do you know what I can use to remove anything before the "-"?

DBMS is MySQL.

Comment: tag the DBMS (MySQL, MS SQL Server, Orcle, etc..) which you are using.

Comment: What should happen if the data looks like this: "7X-123" is the result 7123 or 123 ? Is the input always 6 chars long? is the output always 3 chars long?

Comment: Do you only want numbers in your result set? Is your column format consistent? i.e. not a mix of numbers and letters before and after a '-'?

Comment: If the data set looks like "7X-123", it should be displayed as 123. The input and output do vary as well. I would only like numbers in the data set, but the column format does have a mix of numbers and letters before and after "-"

Answer (score 0):

I hope **split_part (column name, '-', 1)** this will remove the previous value of '-' whereas the **split_part (column name, '-', 2)** can remove the next value of '-' from the above mentioned query.

For example, **split_part("Hi-Hello-World",'-',X)**., here in place of **X** if you mention 1 then it will return Hi, 2 as Hello and 3 as World.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.